# Basic question (part 2) about finite field example, p. 8, of Golan, Linear Algebra a Beginning Graduate Student Ought to Know

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

The example I reference in the subject line reads:

Fields do not have to be infinite. Let $p$ be a positive integer and let $\mathbb{Z}/(p) = {0, 1, . . . , p − 1}$. For each nonnegative integer $n$, let us, for the purposes of this example, denote the remainder after dividing $n$ by $p$ as $[n]_p$ . Thus we note that $[n]_p \in \mathbb{Z}/(p)$ for each nonnegative integer $n$ and that $[i]_p = i$ for all $i \in \mathbb{Z}/(p)$. We now define operations on $\mathbb{Z}/(p)$ by setting $[n]_p + [k]_p = [n + k]_p$ and $[n]_p \cdot [k]_p = [nk]_p$ . It is easy to check that if the integer $p$ is prime then $\mathbb{Z}/(p)$, together with these two operations, is again a field, known as the Galois field of order $p$. This field is usually denoted by $\operatorname{GF}(p)$.

My question (really it is two questions) is:

1. How does one prove the claim: "that $[n]_p \in \mathbb{Z}/(p)$ for each nonnegative integer $n$"?
2. How does one prove the claim: "that $[i]_p=i$ for all $i \in \mathbb{Z}/(p)$"?

At this point, I can only demonstrate to myself numerical examples that hold, but not construct an actual proof for either of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The remainder of the division by $p > 0$ is by construction an $r$, with $0 \le r < p$.
2. If $0 \le r < p$, the remainder of the division of $r$ by $p$ is $r$ itself, as
   \begin{cases}
   r = 0 \cdot p + r\\
   0 \le r < p\\
   \end{cases}
   and quotient and remainder are unique.

---

**Reminder.** One can prove that if $p > 0$, then for each $a$ there exist unique $q, r$ (the quotient and the remainder) such that
\begin{cases}
a = q \cdot p + r\\
0 \le r < p\\
\end{cases}

Comment: Thanks @Andreas Caranti for your help. As per proof by construction technique, am I correct to understand that the phrase "is by construction an $r$, with $0 \le r < p$" is referring to "prior" math, i.e., your Reminder. Having established 1., you are able to construct 2. (I see 2. intuitively is true/obvious - should it be apparent to me that the Reminder formalizes its truth?) and the uniqueness of q and r are again established by reference to your Reminder. Lastly, do you have reference where the content of your Reminder is covered? I rely heavily on books since I learn through self study.

Comment: You're welcome! The Wikipedia is a good starting point https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division

Comment: Thanks for the reference @Andreas Caranti